# Django: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/structure/type/add/

Tags: python, django

I have issues when I enter a string with these french characters: é, è, à, etc...

**I tried two things:**

The first thing is adding this at the very top of my views.py file: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
The second thing is adding this to my settings.py file: `DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'`

And I still get this error message whenever I enter a string with a special character:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://10.0.0.238:8000/admin/structure/type/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.13
Installed Applications:
('apps.structure',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1516.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1470.                     self.log_addition(request, new_object)
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in log_addition
  810.             object_repr=force_text(object),
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  94.                 s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/structure/type/add/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Edit:** My python version is 2.7.13, My django version is 1.8

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 2, you should write Unicode strings with the `u` modifier:

```
print(u"An Unicode string")
print("An ascii string")
```

Comment: Yeah but how about the admin form? how can I alter it?

Comment: Try  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389723/why-is-django-using-ascii-instead-of-utf-8), it seems to be the same issue. Or, if it is possible, try to switch to Python3.

Answer (score -1):

Add in settings file

```
 LANG="en_US.utf8", LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" ,LC_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

or

```
 export LANG="en_US.utf8", LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" , LC_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

### in your shell before starting your django server.

Comment: What make you think the OP wants the locale to be "en_US", and how is this supposed to cure a problem that has nothing to do with the system's encoding ?

Comment: What does this have to do with anything? Plus my locale is not en_US.